# detect if app is sideloaded in windows runtime

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, universal

I am working on a windows phone Runtime app 
I want to know how can I find if the app is side loaded or it downloaded from Store directly ? 
Note : I want to prevent application run when it's sideloaded. I want to prevent crack installation of application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to Write a file in Installed Directory solved the problem . 
Thanks to DJAmol in Xda-Developers.com forum